# Problem writing FDC1004 registers with ESP32 in freeRTOS

Tags: i2c, freertos, esp32, rtos, sensors

I'm trying to read some capative sensors using FDC1004 connected to a ESP32 in freeRTOS. i'm having problems writing FDC1004 registers of 16bits. I programmed a test code reading the ID and writing the configuration registers. The read task is well, i can read correctly the ID of the FDC1004(0x1004), but when i tried to write the register i only read correctly the 8 LSBs. Here is my i2c functions:

```
esp_err_t I2C_write(i2c_port_t i2c_num, uint8_t slave_address, uint8_t data_address, uint8_t *data_wr ,size_t size)
{

    i2c_cmd_handle_t cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();
    i2c_master_start(cmd);
    i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, (slave_address << 1) | WRITE_BIT, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, data_address, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    i2c_master_write(cmd, data_wr, size, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    //i2c_master_write(cmd, data_addres, 1, ACK_CHECK_EN);

    //i2c_master_write(cmd, data_wr, size, ACK_CHECK_EN);

    //i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, data_wr + size - 1, ACK_CHECK_EN);

    i2c_master_stop(cmd);
    esp_err_t ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin(i2c_num, cmd, 1000/portTICK_RATE_MS);
    i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);
    return ret;
}

esp_err_t I2C_read(i2c_port_t i2c_num, uint8_t slave_address, uint8_t *data_addres, uint8_t *data_rd , size_t size){
    if (size == 0) {
        return ESP_OK;
    }
    i2c_cmd_handle_t cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();
    i2c_master_start(cmd);
    i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, (slave_address << 1) | WRITE_BIT, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    i2c_master_write(cmd, data_addres, size, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    i2c_master_stop(cmd);
    esp_err_t ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin(i2c_num, cmd, 1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
    i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);

    cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();
    i2c_master_start(cmd);
    i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, (slave_address << 1) | READ_BIT, ACK_CHECK_EN);
    if (size > 1) {
        i2c_master_read(cmd, data_rd, size - 1, ACK_VAL);
    }
    i2c_master_read_byte(cmd, data_rd + size - 1, NACK_VAL);
    i2c_master_stop(cmd);
    ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin(i2c_num, cmd, 1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
    i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);
    return ret;
}

void FDC1004_writeReg(i2c_port_t i2c_num, uint8_t reg_address, uint16_t data){
    uint8_t tx_buff[2];
    tx_buff[0] = data >> 8;
    tx_buff[1] = data & 0x00FF;

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(I2C_write( i2c_num, FDC_ADDR, reg_address, tx_buff, 2));
    vTaskDelay(20 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
}

uint16_t FDC01004_readReg(i2c_port_t i2c_num, uint8_t reg_address){
    uint8_t read_buff[2];
    uint16_t data;

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(I2C_read( i2c_num, FDC_ADDR, &reg_address, read_buff, 2));

    data = ((uint16_t)(read_buff[0] << 8) | read_buff[1]);
    return data;
}
```

The results when i tried to write 0x10C0, 0x30C0, 0x50C0, 0x70C0 in the registers 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A and  0x0B respectively, are: 0xFFC0, 0xFFC0, 0xFFC0 and 0xFFC0, respectively.

I hope you can help me.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after some test with the code i change the read function as follow:

```
esp_err_t I2C_read(i2c_port_t i2c_num, uint8_t slave_address, uint8_t data_addres, uint8_t *data_rd , size_t size){
if (size == 0) {
    return ESP_OK;
}
i2c_cmd_handle_t cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();
i2c_master_start(cmd);
i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, (slave_address << 1) | WRITE_BIT, ACK_CHECK_EN);
i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, data_addres, ACK_CHECK_EN);
i2c_master_stop(cmd);
esp_err_t ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin(i2c_num, cmd, 1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);

cmd = i2c_cmd_link_create();
i2c_master_start(cmd);
i2c_master_write_byte(cmd, (slave_address << 1) | READ_BIT, ACK_CHECK_EN);
if (size > 1) {
    i2c_master_read(cmd, data_rd, size - 1, ACK_VAL);
}
i2c_master_read_byte(cmd, data_rd + size - 1, NACK_VAL);
i2c_master_stop(cmd);
ret = i2c_master_cmd_begin(i2c_num, cmd, 1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS);
i2c_cmd_link_delete(cmd);
return ret;
}
```

The wrong thing in the read function was that it make a write of the reg address a size times, and only once was needed. This way works for me.